# Exception thrown at 0x0000000000126240 in Crayon X.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing path 0x0000000000126240

Tags: c#, rust

I'm trying to inject a Rust dll from C# in Visual Studio. Here is the calling function C# code snippet:

```cs
public static int Inject(String windowName) {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(windowName)[0];
            IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, true, process.Id);
            IntPtr loadlibraryaddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

            string dllpath = @"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\dll\target\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\release\dll.dll";

            UIntPtr byteswritten = UIntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr allocmemaddress = VirtualAllocEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)((dllpath.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
            
            WriteProcessMemory(
                handle,
                allocmemaddress,
                Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dllpath),
                (uint) ((dllpath.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))),
                out byteswritten
            );

            CreateRemoteThread(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadlibraryaddress, allocmemaddress, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            return 1;
        }
```

Calling code (Form1.cs:22) `int PlsMakeItWork = dll.Inject("notepad.exe");`

Here is the Rust DllMain function declaration:

```rust
unsafe extern "system" fn DllMain(dll_module: HINSTANCE, call_reason: DWORD, reserved: LPVOID) -> BOOL {
    //blablabla
    true as BOOL
}
```

And here is where Visual Studio says the exception occurs (dll_dllmain.cpp:281)

```cpp
result = DllMain(instance, reason, reserved);
```

I dont even know how to solve this issue, please guys, help me out, thanks!!!